# How to repeat x, n times?

Tags: vim

I need to remove n characters, starting from cursor. I tried to type x10, as to repeat x 10 times. I expected to delete 10 characters starting from cursor location, but that did not happen.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 10x, not x10.

Silly chars to ensure there are 30...